# Hyperref problem with ntheorem theoremstyle{break}

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, ntheorem

I'd like to use the package `hyperref` together with `ntheorem` and its option `\theoremstyle{break}`, because I want to separate the title of a theorem from the theorem's content. My problem is that the hyperlinks inside the first line of a theorem are drawn in a too-big frame that is vertically higher than the line-height, like in this example: [image]

My code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem,hyperref}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremindent20pt 
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{cri}{Criterion}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\label{sec:test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
\section{Second Section}
According to Section \ref{sec:test}, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\begin{cri}[Example]
According to Section \ref{sec:test}, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{cri}

\end{document}
```

I have experimented with `\vspace`, but this didn't work either. I'm a LaTeX newbe. Could you pls. advise how to fix this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is present not only with `\ref` but with `\autoref` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the ntheorem implementation the title of the theorem is actually a part of the first line, and so this line has a large height which is used by the link to calculate the link rectangle; you would get the same e.g. with a large strut. The only thing you can do is to put the \ref in a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem,hyperref}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremindent20pt
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{cri}{Criterion}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\label{sec:test}
\begin{cri}[Example]
According to Section \ref{sec:test}, %large height
\end{cri}

\rule{0pt}{24pt}\ref{sec:test} %large height

\begin{cri}[Example]
According to Section \mbox{\ref{sec:test}}, %smaller height
\end{cri}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great! thank you!